# How to check recovery status progress of a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am a newish SQL programmer, working with a production data warehouse with 250GB of data. I wrote (in hindsight) a very cumbersome massive query with a for-each loop that must of had an infinite loop somewhere because it ran way too long and was taking up more and more memory. At this point, I decided to cancel the query, but it was still executing (I now understand it was rolling back).

I attempted to kill the rollback process with `KILL SPID` which didn't really do anything. I did `KILL SPID WITH STATUSONLY` which returned `transaction rollback in progress. Estimated rollback completion: 0%. Estimated time remaining: 0 seconds`.

At this point, I decided the server must be stuck so I restarted the server. When it came back, in SSMS, the affected database now says `MyDatabase (In Recovery)`. I understand that it's either completing the rollback or checking the data integrity? Is there any command to see how much progress it's making or or much time is left?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to access server logs using SQL. In case master database is online. So checking logs directly is best option but not always possible. (on Linux logs tend to be unreadable binary blobs, I guess you need SSMS to read them)

Set the database to “master,” and replace the variable in the first line, “@DBName,” with the database you wish to investigate.

```sql
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(64) = 'Warehouse'

DECLARE @ErrorLog AS TABLE([LogDate] CHAR(24), [ProcessInfo] VARCHAR(64), [TEXT] VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @ErrorLog
EXEC master..sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Recovery of database', @DBName

INSERT INTO @ErrorLog
EXEC master..sp_readerrorlog 0, 1, 'Recovery completed', @DBName

SELECT TOP 1
    @DBName AS [DBName]
   ,[LogDate]
   ,CASE
      WHEN SUBSTRING([TEXT],10,1) = 'c'
      THEN '100%'
      ELSE SUBSTRING([TEXT], CHARINDEX(') is ', [TEXT]) + 4,CHARINDEX(' complete (', [TEXT]) - CHARINDEX(') is ', [TEXT]) - 4)
      END AS PercentComplete
   ,CASE
      WHEN SUBSTRING([TEXT],10,1) = 'c'
      THEN 0
      ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING([TEXT], CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) + 13,CHARINDEX(' seconds remain', [TEXT]) - CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) - 13) AS FLOAT)/60.0
      END AS MinutesRemaining
   ,CASE
      WHEN SUBSTRING([TEXT],10,1) = 'c'
      THEN 0
      ELSE CAST(SUBSTRING([TEXT], CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) + 13,CHARINDEX(' seconds remain', [TEXT]) - CHARINDEX('approximately', [TEXT]) - 13) AS FLOAT)/60.0/60.0
      END AS HoursRemaining
   ,[TEXT]
FROM @ErrorLog ORDER BY CAST([LogDate] as datetime) DESC, [MinutesRemaining]
```

source: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4832/script-to-find-out-when-sql-server-recovery-will-finish/

Answer (score 0):

Found it by myself, for anybody else with the same problem.

Object Explorer > *YourServerName* > Management > SQL Server Logs > *most recent*/Current

Opened up a log viewer that shows the recovery process of the database:

'Recovery of database 'MyDatabase' (10) is 55% complete (approximately 1066 seconds remain)'

Today I learned a valuable lesson about for-each loops in SQL and also killing server processes in a panic.

Comment: But you missed the most important lesson - NEVER run sql that has not been tested and verified as correct in a production database. That is even more important when the writer is "a newish SQL programmer". And if that code changes the state of the database, make sure you have a disaster recovery plan.

Comment: What's a good way to handle this? I have a test server on my local desktop. Should I just clone the tables I need to my test server? It won't be up to date data but it would still be a lot of volume.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get some information from the DMV `sys.dm_exec_requests`, although it's not perfectly accurate and often shows 0%. If SSMS managed to get it then it would probably show the same:

```sql
SELECT command, percent_complete, start_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE session_id = @otherSPID;
```